# handling the cancel of window.onbeforeunload prompt

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Is there any way I can handle the cancel and reload action of the window.onbeforeunload event of javascript
something like this ...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
       
       if( e.cancelled ) {
           
           console.log('user has not agreed to reload');
            
       } else {
          console.log('user agrees to reload');
        }

     return '';
   }
```

I have searched for it on [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) but there is no mention about this

Comment: Its name says it all `before unload`. If the user exits nothing can continue and vice versa

Comment: @TachibanaShin that's just a statement ... If you have any other workaround for achieving this , that would be really helpful